# Triggering from a form or something similar

Tags: google-apps-script

Ok sorry for the novice question here, I did a lot of research but can't find my way on this.

I have an app script that has `var clientName= ('Last name, First name - Company')`

and uses this data to create a client folder, with sub folders and even duplicates some template files and changes them based on the client's name (what was input)

This all works fine you just have to go to the script, change the var clientName and then run it. That works fine for me, but I want to get my staff using this script when new clients arrive.

So ideally I could just have a very simple form where my staff puts in the information I need (last name, first name - company name) and then hits submit and the form passes the value to the script and then runs it and confirms so my staff knows it was complete.

I have figured all the scripting out by searching and piecing things together, but I can't seem to find the right direction to do this. I would even be happy with a small box they fill out and run, it doesn't have to be a google form, I guess it could even be a spreadsheet that gets reused, but this would need to reset itself.

Comment: Review Apps Script triggers (for a Google Form solution). Otherwise, there are a number of ways to prompt the keyboard user that initiated a script to input data for consumption by the script. Review the Browser / UI classes, and guides on Sidebars. For now, your question is too broad to be answerable - it has no specific programming question that is definitively answerable.

Comment: Thank you for this info, I must be missing something because I cant find anything about Google Apps and how to pass a variable to a script in a form. I will keep looking though, my search skills are failing me, and thats weird because i know this should be very simple. Thank you for your time!

Comment: I have figured out how to attach the script to a form and run the script when the form is submitted, but I cant figure out the most important part. How do I get the entered information in the questions Client Name to pass its value to the var clientName in the script. Im so lost on this!

Comment: Review the event object associated with the "form submit" installed trigger.